# Xamarin sqliteAsyncConnection Could not open database file

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, sqlite-net

I'm using Visual Studio For Mac. I'm getting an exception error in my previewer stating

> "An exception occurred while rendering the control".

When I click the exclamation mark for details it states

> SQLite.SqlLiteException Could not open Database file.

I can't find anything wrong with it. It runs fine in the simulator but doesn't work in previewer.

SQLiteConnection:

```
 public class SQLiteDb : ISOLiteDb
{
    public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "MySQLite.db3"); 
       var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
       return conn;

    }
```

Resp:

```
public class UserService
{
    private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
    public UserService()
    {
        _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISOLiteDb>().GetConnection();

    }

    public async Task AddUser(User user)
    {
        await _connection.CreateTableAsync<User>();
        await _connection.InsertAsync(user);

    }
```

viewModel:

```
  private UserService _userService;
    private readonly IPageService _iPageService;

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public SignOnViewModel(IPageService pageService)
    {
        _userService = new UserService();
        _iPageService = pageService;
    }
```

code behind:

```
 public partial class SignOnPage : ContentPage
{
    public SignOnPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new SignOnViewModel(new PageService());
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void CreateAccount(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        (BindingContext as SignOnViewModel).AddUser();
    }
```

Comment: `...runs fine in the simulator but doesn't work in previewer....` Do you mean Xamarin Live Player? If so, does it work in the device when you directly deploy to it (i.e. not using Xamarin Live Player) and if it does work properly that way, post an issue over at developercommunity.visualstudio.com and let the Microsoft Devs look into it.

Comment: I think he means the XAML previewer in VS

Comment: Hi SushiHangover, thanks for responding. Yes, I'm referring to the Xamarin Previewer in VS that renders your controls as you add them. When I deploy it to the simulator it doesn't throw an exception but in the Xamarin Previewer I can't see my controls I have added because of the sqliteException. I figured out what's causing the error. In the viewModel it doesn't like the _userService = new UserService in the ctor. I don't understand why it doesn't like it.